# Aws greengrass core sdk for node js - how do I retrive the mqtt message?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I am writing a lambda function in node js which is deployed to ggc. It is triggered by a mqtt-message from node red. But I have no idea how to retrive the information sent from node red. I guess that I have to use the context-object, but I dont know how. Right now im sending a simple json-string, but I probably want to send binary in the future.